# Help identifying giant blue LEGO Bionicle set

Tags: bionicle

I have what appears to be a giant Bionicle. The head is the size of a small human head almost the size of a mask.

It is blue in colour and in 5 bags. It looks like more than 100 pieces. The instructions and box are lost. No idea what it is.

Any ideas? Can post pics if needed.

Comment: Picture would definitely help. There are a number of sets I can think that this might be.

Comment: It's better to post pic

Answer (score 3):

Gadunka (8922) came somewhere around 2007, and was part of the underwater themed bionicle sets. When assembled it is quite big. Maybe this is set you were looking for?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another candidate would be the [8894 Piraka Stronghold](https://brickset.com/sets/8894-1/Piraka-Stronghold) or "Lava Chamber Gate":
[image: 8894 main Image]
as it contains the largest Bionicle mask/head piece in blue.